# tadalist.com drap and drop list reordering

Tags: asp.net

tadalist.com has a feature that allows you to reorder a list by dragging and dropping the list items.  I'd like to do this on an asp.net page with list items stored in a database.  How can this be done so that the new order is saved to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past in 2 ways:

1. Use the [Reorder List from the Ajax Control Toolkit.](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ReorderList/ReorderList.aspx)
2. Use a javascript library like [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) to sort the list and call a webservice after the sort is finished to save the order to the database. Here is a [link to an example on how to do this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/332037.aspx).

The second requires more work but allows for a cleaner/more flexible design.